# django logging - django.request logger and extra context

Tags: python, django, logging, django-settings

Am on django 1.3., python 2.6

In the django docs here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/logging/#django-request
it says that messages have the following extra context: status and request.
How do you get these to show up in the debug file? i tried in my logging config something like:

```
'formatters': {        
        'simple_debug': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(module)s %(message)s %(request.user)s',        
        }
    },
```

but that causes the overall logging to fail (i.e. no logging output happens)

---

**EDIT:** 
So immediately after submitting the question i came across this:
http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/af682beb1e4af7f6/ace3338348e92a21

can someone help explain/elaborate on

> All the quote from the docs really means is that all the places inside
>   of django where django.request is used, the request is explicitly
>   passed in as part of extra.

where is request explicitly passed in as part of extra to?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't use `request.user` in the format string, as %-formatting doesn't handle that. You could use a format string such as

```
'[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(module)s %(message)s %(user)s'
```

and, in your logging call, use something like

```
logger.debug('My message with %s', 'args', extra={'user': request.user})
```

The `extra` dict is merged into the logging event record, which ends up with a `user` attribute, and this then gets picked up through the format string and appears in the log.

If using the `django.request` logger, the status_code and the request will be passed in the `extra` dict by Django. If you need the `request.user`, you'll probably need to add a `logging.Filter` which does something like:

```
class RequestUserFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.user = record.request.user
        return True
```

so that you can show the user in the formatted output.

Comment: what if i don't want to use `logger.debug(*)` means for production env

Answer (score 7):

The [django-requestlogging middleware plugin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-requestlogging/) makes it easy to log request-related information without adjusting all your logging calls to add the `request` with the `extra` parameter.  It's then just a matter of configuring your loggers.

The following items can be logged when using django-requestlogging:

- username
- http_user_agent
- path_info
- remote_add
- request_method
- server_protocol

Comment: Request is being set to None always. Can you please help. @brki

Comment: Works like charm. i think this is a better solution then the above one, as i dont have to change all my existing logs.