# Cannot access request.data in log filter

Tags: python, django, logging, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework, and following this [django logging - django.request logger and extra context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292082/django-logging-django-request-logger-and-extra-context/) answer to include custom data to my log records. When trying to access `record.request.data` inside `filter()` (to store it to `record.data` as that answer suggests) I get `RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream`. I have tried many things, none of which worked. Cannot manually rewind the request's data stream, nor get a fresh copy of the request object. I never manually access `request.body`, as the SO answers suggest avoiding. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```py
import logging

from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings


class RequestInfoFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        parsers = [parser() for parser in api_settings.DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES]
        authenticators = [
            auth() for auth in api_settings.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES]
        request = Request(
            record.request, parsers=parsers, authenticators=authenticators)

        record.method = request.method
        record.query_params = request.query_params
        record.data = request.data  # RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

        return True
```

Note that this happens only when logging views that access `request.data` themselves. If they don't, no error occurs.

Comment: `request.data` is accessible in classes which inherit from `Apiview` or if you're using function base add a decorator `@apiview(['GET'])`

Comment: @AtifShafi I know but this doesn't answer my question. As shown in the code, I explicitly create a `rest_framework.request.Request` object, which, then, has a `data` attribute. It's just that if `request.data` has been accessed by the view before it reaches the log filter, I get `RawPostDataException`. If it hasn't been accessed I don't get the error.

Comment: Just to confirm, it doesn't work with `record.request.data`?

Comment: @BrianD If the view that is being logged accesses/references `request.data`, then `record.request.data` causes a `RawPostDataException`, indeed.